# Wordpress redirect issue from clean wp install to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a problem with a wordpress site as follows:

A website was built on http://example-domain.com.
I have build a wordpress site on http://example-domain.com/wordpress.
I want to delete everything in public.html folder and put a clean wordpress there.

The problem is that after I installed the clean wordpress, I keep getting redirected to the /wordpress subdirectory.

What I have tried:
Changed the site URL and home from example http://example-domain.com/wordpress to http://example-domain.com, copied a clean htaccess file in the new wp instalation.

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Before, I had 2 htaccess files, one just like the one mentioned above, that was located in the subdirectory and one in the root like this:

```html
DirectoryIndex /wordpress/index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
<IfModule mime_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Extra info: It is not a cache or cookie nor browser issue.

Update:
I was watching the Network tab in dev tools on Chrome and saw this error.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you changed the existing database urls from  http://example-domain.com/wordpress to http://example-domain.com ?

Export the existing database, open in a text editor, do find-replace for the url's(from subdirectory to root directory) as mentioned above. Then import it into the new database. Once done, a fresh htaccess like this in the public/html root folder should be working fine.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I changed them from wp-options table in the database. Is this what you are reffering to?

Comment: Yes, wp-options as well as entire database. Page url's are also saved throughout other tables like post's and post meta. Try running the replacement operation on entire database and upload it.

Comment: I updated the post with a picture, can you check please to see if it is relevant ?

Comment: Yes, its happening because of the wrong htaccess. Take a back up of the root htaccess file which has this code "DirectoryIndex /wordpress/index.php", put the fresh htaccess in root after changing all the urls in entire database. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I cleared all my browsing data, because I still had the error in incognito, and the permanent error disappeared. However, now I am getting a Internal Error 500

Comment: Can you share the the root htaccess file that you have put in public/html? Also, please confirm that you have done replacement on entire database and uploaded the database.

Comment: I changed the database as you said and I still get the Internal 500 Error. THe htaccess file I have, is the clean one mentioned in the question

Comment: I created a clean wordpress database, and when I access the site, usually the wp installer windows pops up, but now, I still get 500 error

Comment: Hmm strange, should be working fine. Hey @TorjescuSergiu, if you don't mind, can you share the access to the site, would be happy to help you out on this. Chat option is not working in stack I see. Here's my email: mdhassan6767@gmail.com